# efficient usage of same model for multiple application rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having rails application with two modules.

One is for `customer posts` and other is for `admin panel`. I have created my `customer` module. Once customer module completed i am thinking about having same model for admin too.

How can i efficiently use same model for customer and admin modules.

Can any one suggest me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have models with the same name but in different namespace.

You can create module in models folder:

```
module ModuleName
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'module_name_'
  end
end
```

and then models for this module will be in models/module_name directory, like:

```
class ModuleName::ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :attr1, :attr2
end
```

your migrations should be like this:

```
class CreateModuleNameModelNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :module_name_model_names do |t|    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I think it is rather clear solution if you want the same model name for different application modules.

Try `rails g module_name/model_name` - it will suggest you the structure of model namespaces.

Also look for STI (Single Table Inheritance) for example [here](http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails).